# Стили Select в мобильной версии сайта на Android

Tags: javascript, android, css, select

Select в мобильной версии браузера открывает свой дефолтный выпадающий список. При этом css стили к option не применяются. Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему. [[image: Отображение на Android][1]]

Comment: ссылка на сайт: https://resnichki.com.ua/

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.